# Pipe gets changed from PDF

Tags: windows, copy-paste

When using MikTex I've noticed the pipe | (vertical bar) looks fine in a pdf when when saved out as text it gets changed to j so

> Always five, acting as one | Dedicated | Inseparable | Invincible

Becomes

> Always five, acting as one j Dedicated j Inseparable j Invincible

I don't think it's a latex problem, but since I create the pdf as a tex file I wanted to know if anyone has experienced this? I've already thought of substituting pipe for a hyphen but I don't really want to compromise my text. What are the alternatives?

Here is the tex file:

```
% document class
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{memoir}

%set pdf to print transparency properly
\pdfminorversion 7

% stuff
\pagestyle{empty} % no page numbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}     % no paragraph indentation

% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans} %% Alternatively
%% use the option 'defaultsans' instead of 'default' to replace the
%% sans serif font only.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cmap}

% Start The Fans Please!
\begin{document}

 Always five, acting as one | Dedicated | Inseparable | Invincible\\

 Always five, acting as one \textbar Dedicated \textbar Inseparable \textbar Invincible\\ 


\end{document}
```

And the text file when saved as text from Adobe Reader

Always1ve,actingasone|Dedicated|Inseparable|Invincible 
Always1ve,actingasone|Dedicated|Inseparable|Invincible

Comment: Please post a code to replicate this issue. Did you try to use different viewers?

Comment: Which font encoding (as per `\usepackage{[...]{fontenc}`) are you using?

Comment: Have you tried to use `\textbar` instead of the pipe | directly?

Comment: And did you have a look at `cmap` ([here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmap?lang=de) etc.)?

Comment: Your code compiles just fine for me and I'm able to copy & paste properly.

Comment: Idem as @TeXnician, I've also saved the pdf as txt from Acrobat Reader ad the pipes are OK...

Comment: I think it may be (but not limited to) earlier versions of Adobe Reader as I was able to produce the text file with clean pipes |||, but stil with the "Always1ve" error

Answer (score 2):

I have no problems with the pipes and the spaces works ok too, but the fi-Ligature is copied like in your as one. You can correct it like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{memoir}

%set pdf to print transparency properly
\pdfminorversion 7

% stuff
\pagestyle{empty} % no page numbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}     % no paragraph indentation

% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans} %% Alternatively
%% use the option 'defaultsans' instead of 'default' to replace the
%% sans serif font only.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}

 Always five, acting as one | Dedicated | Inseparable | Invincible\\

\end{document}
```